# transaction isolation, record locks and concurrent insertions in table

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I have several processes trying to insert the same data into an InnoDB MySQL table.

This table is basically

```
id : int primary autoincrement
name: varchar(100)
```

For historical reasons, there is no unique constraints on the name column and I can't add it now.

However, I want to prevent duplicates insertions from concurrent processes.

I ended up writing this kind of SQL script :

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

SELECT name FROM table WHERE name IN ('alice', 'bob') FOR UPDATE;

INSERT INTO table (name)
SELECT 'alice' FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'alice') LIMIT 1;

INSERT INTO table (name)
SELECT 'bob' FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'bob') LIMIT 1;

COMMIT;
```

from mysql documentation, record locks ["prevent any other transaction from inserting, updating, or deleting rows"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html)

However, I'm not completely sure that I'll be prevented from duplicate insertions.

I can also lock the table using

```
LOCK TABLE table WRITE;
```

but that will prevent any other session to run concurrently as they won't be able to acquire the lock from their side, forcing me to implement a retry/sleep logic in the code around DB access.

What is the correct and smooth way to have the desired behavior ?

Comment: How many rows in the table?  Which version of MySQL?  Wny can't you do the `ALTER` to add `UNIQUE(name)`?

Comment: 10 millions. Because of historical reasons (many duplicates already inside which I can't sanitize)

Comment: But you want to add new rows and make sure they are not dups?

Comment: indeed that's the point

Comment: As long as there are already dups, I suggest avoiding future dups is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Bite the bullet and fix it.  It might take only a few minutes for 10M rows.

```
(stop writes to the system)

CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE table;
ALTER TABLE new_table
    ADD UNIQUE(name);
INSERT INTO new_table (id, name)
    SELECT MAX(id), name
        FROM table
        GROUP BY name;
RENAME TABLE table TO old_table,
             new_table TO table;

(allow writes again)

DROP TABLE old_table;   -- when you are comfortable that the change was good
```

Henceforth, use `IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table
    (name)
    VALUES (?);
```

(`id` values will continue to increase, but at least no new dup names will occur.)

(If you have more columns than those 2, adjust accordingly.)